# Summarize Multiple Lines of code into one

Tags: python

Quick question: How could I write my code cleaner? Can I write the 'with' and 'if' statemants all together in one line without repeating myself? - Thankful for all tips.

```py
with open('Requirements_good.txt') as myfile:
    Sentence = myfile.readlines()
    Sentence = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), Sentence))

#get data
with open('Badwords_conjunctive.txt') as myfile:
    conjunctive_list = myfile.readlines()
    conjunctive_list = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), conjunctive_list))
with open('Badwords_unprecise.txt') as myfile:
    unprecise_list = myfile.readlines()
    unprecise_list = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), unprecise_list))
with open('Badwords_other.txt') as myfile:
    other_list = myfile.readlines()
    other_list = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), other_list))


if any(word in Sentence for word in unprecise_list):
    print('Your words of choice have unprecise definitions')

if any(word in Sentence for word in conjunctive_list):
    print('Conjunctive should rather be avoided')

if any(word in Sentence for word in other_list):
    print('You wrote a word that should rather be avoided')
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview.

Comment: Probably it is better at CodeReview, but you should provide more informations: Are those three possibilities the end, or do plan to add more? If you want to add more, you should think about adding a new abstraction layer. One easy solution is to merge the lists first and then check the list. Also how big are the lists and how often is this function called, because you load all data in the memory. Your use-case is not clear, do you excpect some kind of bottleneck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

`with` and `if` can be used together like this:

```
with open('Badwords_unprecise.txt') as myfile:
    unprecise_list = myfile.readlines()
    unprecise_list = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), unprecise_list))
    if any(word in Sentence for word in unprecise_list):
        print('Your words of choice have unprecise definitions')
```

And this can be reduced one line:

```py
with open('Badwords_unprecise.txt') as myfile: if any(word in Sengence for word in myfile.readlines())
```

But, according to PEP8, writing too long lines is not a recommended habit.
Readability is one of the key features of Python language.
It's better to separate long lines to shorter lines.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def fn(file_name):
    data = []
    with open(file_name) as myfile:
        data = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), myfile.readlines()))
    return data
Sentence = fn("Requirements_good.txt")
conjunctive_list = fn("Badwords_conjunctive.txt")
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This likely belongs on Code Review. I do, however, want to share a refactored version, I'm not satisfied with the current answers.

```py
with open('Requirements_good.txt') as curr_file:
    sentence = [line.strip() for line in curr_file]

with open('Badwords_conjunctive.txt') as curr_file:
    conjunctive_list = [line.strip() for line in curr_file]

with open('Badwords_unprecise.txt') as curr_file:
    unprecise_list = [line.strip() for line in curr_file]

with open('Badwords_other.txt') as curr_file:
    other_list = [line.strip() for line in curr_file]

if any(word in sentence for word in unprecise_list):
    print('Your words of choice have unprecise definitions')

if any(word in sentence for word in conjunctive_list):
    print('Conjunctive should rather be avoided')

if any(word in sentence for word in other_list):
    print('You wrote a word that should rather be avoided')
```

I think this makes as few assumptions about the rest of the program as possible.